# Which is the best way to write data into files?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, io, multiprocessing

I am pulling data from tables and writing into files. Here I have to pull data from 11 tables and then write into files.

So currently what I am doing,

```
def get_data_from_table_to_txt(con, sql, filename):
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(sql)
    with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
        for row in cur.fetchall():
            fp.write(row)


get_data_from_table_to_txt(con, sql1, filename1)
get_data_from_table_to_txt(con, sql2, filename2)
get_data_from_table_to_txt(con, sql3, filename3)
get_data_from_table_to_txt(con, sql4, filename4)
get_data_from_table_to_txt(con, sql5, filename5)
.
.
.
```

If you seen above code, It is fetching table and then writing into file. And this process is sequential unloading data.This process is very slow. So I am thinking to implement multi-threading. **is the multi-threading good for this process ?**

Answer (score 0):

How big is the data? you could keep the file open and only save at the end or put the dbdata into a variable and save it all at the end so you stop writing all the time. If you multithread be careful about order if it matters. You could use a list and put each sql into its element and combine at the end.